# Get rid of a JOIN LATERAL

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have two tables looking like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE log
    (program int, time int, a int, b int)
;
    
INSERT INTO log
    (program, time, a, b)
VALUES
    (1, 5, 3, 4),
    (1, 10, 5, 6),
    (2, 5, 7, 8)
;


CREATE TABLE params
    (program int, time int, a_ref int, b_ref int)
;
    
INSERT INTO params
    (program, time, a_ref,b_ref)
VALUES
    (1, 3, 4, 5),
    (1, 4, 6, 7),
    (2, 6, 8, 9)
;
```

For each entry in `log` I can find a corresponding entry in `params` (imagine: reference parameters for the `program`), and given a `log`, I need to locate the most recent entry with the same `program` and a time stamp which is smaller than the `log` timestamp.

A working query is this:

```sql
SELECT log.a, log.b, params.a_ref, params.b_ref 
FROM log 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   select * 
   from params 
   where params.time < log.time 
     and params.program = log.program 
   ORDER BY time 
   DESC LIMIT 1
) params ON log.program = params.program
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d9a65e/2)

When I understand it correctly, I have to imagine the nested query `(SELECT .. ORDER BY)` as something that is executed for every row in `log`.

Is there a chance to get rid of it?

Comment: It's not uncommon that this is actually _faster_ than other solutions. Do you actually have a performance problem?

Comment: Don't expect sane behaviour from a DBMS if your tables don't have any structure. At least add PKs + FKs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get rid of the lateral join is to use a `distinct on ()` in the derived table and add the restriction on the time column to the join condition:

```
SELECT log.a, log.b, params.a_ref, params.b_ref 
FROM log 
  LEFT JOIN (
     select distinct on (program) *
     from params 
     order by program, time desc 
  ) params ON log.program = params.program 
          and params.time < log.time
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=01da1c0006124d74664697da5f99a9d1)

Comment: Looks good! I am now evaluating where the performance issue comes from - of course a proper foreign key would solve this, but now I can at least evaluate the two options whether one can compensate for the layout issue.

Comment: This will not return the same result of any params exist which are more recent than that the log is for the same program

Answer (score 0):

SQL-standard solution:

- join `log` with all possible `params`
- for each possible `params` compute its order as distance from `log.time` (and sort last values that are beyond bound)
- rows with rank 1 are result you want

```sql
select a, b, a_ref, b_ref
from (
  select log.a, log.b
       , case when log.time > params.time then params.a_ref else null end as a_ref
       , case when log.time > params.time then params.b_ref else null end as b_ref
       , row_number() over (partition by log.a, log.b, log.program order by log.time <= params.time, log.time - params.time) as rn
  from log
  join params on log.program = params.program
) x
where rn = 1
```

[Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/57c8f/5)